# How to speed up first request for local Rails UI tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, poltergeist, spinach, rails-spring

I am using spinach, Capybara, and Poltergeist together to write automated UI tests. I have been trying to speed up running tests locally. I am using Spring which helps a little with the environment loading. However, the first request (`visit`) to the app server that Poltergeist starts is slow because Rails has to compile the assets the first time. I have tried starting a locally server in the test environment and then doing this in my spinach `env.rb` file:

```
::Capybara.run_server = false
::Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:#{ENV['TEST_SERVER_PORT']}"
```

This makes debugging difficult because the web server is running in a different process than the spinach process. Also, precompiling assets is not a good solution because I don't want to have to run it every time I am tweaking things in a JS file and then running the tests to verify my changes.

Bottom line: *has anyone figured out how to make the first test server request be faster?*

Answer (score 0):

You could use parallel tests for Spinach

```
https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests
```

It probably won't solve the issue with first request but it can speed up running all tests - which still might be beneficial for you

Comment: We already use `parallel_tests` for our CI pipeline, but this is more for our development workflow. I rerun the same test many times as I am developing a feature or fixing a feature. Waiting for the assets every time is a pain. Using unit tests instead would "solve" this but we are avoiding adding lots of unit tests if our UI tests already give the necessary coverage.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would set up [`rspec-retry`](https://github.com/NoRedInk/rspec-retry). Second, try this in `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) { visit '/' if defined?(visit) }
end
```